# Single phase appliance on 3-phase circuit

Tags: power

Is it possible to have a single phase socket on a 3-phase circuit?

It is a 3-phase radial circuit on a 16 A breaker. The last 3-phase socket on the circuit basically wants converting into a single phase socket to be able to plug the fridge in, it is a 2 kW fridge.

Comment: There is a neutral there so currently I have dropped L2 and L3 out of the 3phase socket that is previous to the one in question and just used L1, N and E as normal for the single phase and was getting 230v at the new socket. The fridge was pre wired with single phase socket on and the installer said cable was sufficient for it it just needs the single phase socket.

Comment: So, you've answered your own question?

Comment: Haha never used this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared the voltage levels, so it makes it hard to answer perfectly, thing is you have two options to single phase... if you somehow got access to neutral, you can take a phase and neutral and connect to that. Neutral and ground are different.

The other option you have is the voltage of your fridge allows it is to take the voltage between two of the phases of your three phase system and use that as a single phase, this is higher than the phase to neutral voltage by about 1.7 times (square root of 3).

Once you know which option you can do — phase to neutral or between phases — the next thing you gotta do is calculate the current for the power rating of the fridge and see if your cables can handle that, on top of the current of whatever else is connected to it.

If you can please post more info of the fridge (what voltage is written on it) and what voltage your 3-phase system is, better advice can be given.

Comment: There is a neutral there so currently I have dropped L2 and L3 out of the 3phase socket that is previous to the one in question and just used L1, N and E as normal for the single phase and was getting 230v at the new socket. The fridge was pre wired with single phase socket on and the installer said cable was sufficient for it it just needs the single phase socke